# How to play 3gp audio file in Android using default player in the device?

Tags: android

I need to play an 3gp audio file  stored in my sd card location, to play it with my default media player in my HTC device.

Code :

```
 public class AudioRecorder extends Activity {

     private static final String CAMERA_STATUS = "camera_upload";
        private static final String GALLERY_STATUS = "gallery_upload";
        MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        static String path = "audio-android.3gp";
        Button startRecording;
        Button stopRecording;
        Button save;
        Button palyAudio;
        private Context context;


     private String sanitizePath(String path) {
        if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
            path = "/" + path;
        }
        if (!path.contains(".")) {
            path += ".3gp";
        }
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + path;
        }



     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.audio_recording);
        context = this;
        /**
         * Creates a new audio recording at the given path (relative to root of
         * SD card).
         */

        this.path = sanitizePath(path);

        startRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startRecording);
        stopRecording = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopRecording);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetRecording);
        palyAudio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playRecorded);

startRecording.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                stopRecording.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                startRecording.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        });

        stopRecording.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            stopRecording.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            startRecording.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                            stop();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        });


        palyAudio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
             playAudio();
             //startMediaPlayer();

            }

        });

        }

        /**
         * 
         * play the recorded audio
         * 
         */
        public void playAudio() {
        try {

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri data = Uri.parse(path);
           // Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, data);  
            intent.setDataAndType(data, "audio/mp3");
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        }


      /**
         * Starts a new recording.
         */
        public void start() throws IOException {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();

        String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state
                + ".");
        }

        // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
        File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
        System.out.println("start() directory >  " + directory);
        if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
        }

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);                 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);    recorder.setOutputFile(path); 
        recorder.prepare();               
        recorder.start(); 

        }

        /**
         * Stops a recording that has been previously started.
         */
        public void stop() throws IOException {
        recorder.stop(); // Stops recording.
        recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused

        }


    }
```

Comment: can you tell me how can you find your answer to play 3gp

Comment: Dr.nik  actually.. i recorded auido and save it in 3gp in sdcard.. after that i playesd the audio...

Comment: i know it but can you tell me how to play 3gp file from sdcard

Comment: because i got trouble to play

Comment: mediaPlayerStopped = false;
     mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
     Uri data = Uri.parse(path);
     mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, data);
     mediaPlayer.prepare();
     mediaPlayer.start();

Comment: static String path = "audio-android.3gp";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5188/discussion-between-jennifer-and-dr-nik)

Comment: i havent access to chat please continue here

Comment: ** 
* Sets the value for path 
* 
* @param path 
* the path to set 
*/ 
public static void setPath(String path) { 
AudioRecorder.path = path; 
} 

private String sanitizePath(String path) { 
if (!path.startsWith("/")) { 
path = "/" + path; 
} 
if (!path.contains(".")) { 
path += ".3gp"; 
} 
return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
+ path; 
}

Comment: if i am set .mp3 file then it will play but when i am play 3gp it not

Comment: i save the file in 3gp format & then tried to play with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(t);
        path = "/sdcard/sample.mp3";
                    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Comment: can we call any intent to play the audio

Answer (score 5):

So this is actually quite a headbanger, but here's how to do it:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + yourfilepath);
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
it.setDataAndType(uri,"video/3gpp");
startActivity(it);
```

The key is to set the video MIME, even for the audio file. Don't ask me why this works, it just does.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri playUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/music/an.mp3");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, playUri); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have given this bt below expection is thrown : 05-04 17:26:05.161: WARN/System.err(4819): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/audio-android.3gp }

Answer (score 1):

Use VideoView (see [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html)) to get over the use of surface and states, it uses the native player.

```
String path = getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to/file/in/sdcard";
VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideoViewId);
vv.setVideoPath(path);
vv.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri data = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/sample.mp3");
        intent.setDataAndType(data,"audio/mp3");

        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Comment: @Androider : I have given this bt below expection is thrown : 05-04 17:26:05.161: WARN/System.err(4819): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/audio-android.3gp }

Comment: The above code is inside an Activity and dont forget to include that activity in Androidmanifest.xml.

Comment: @Androider:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882656/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-android-intent-action-view

Comment: Change intent.setDataAndType as intent.setDataAndType(data,"audio/3gpp").
if the type is video then change to intent.setDataAndType(data,"video/3gpp") or simply use intent.setData("video/*").