# No Activity found to handle Intent : android.intent.action.VIEW

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, galaxy-tab

This is my code to play the recorded audio 3gp file

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri data = Uri.parse(path);
        intent.setDataAndType(data, "audio/mp3");
        startActivity(intent);
```

But while running it in my HTC device (Android 2.2 Froyo) shows an exception:

```
05-04 16:37:37.597: WARN/System.err(4065): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/audio-android.3gp typ=audio/mp3 }
05-04 16:37:37.597: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1567)
05-04 16:37:37.597: INFO/ActivityManager(92): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/audio-android.3gp typ=audio/mp3 }
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1537)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2858)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2964)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at com.ey.camera.AudioRecorder.playAudio(AudioRecorder.java:244)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at com.ey.camera.AudioRecorder$4.onClick(AudioRecorder.java:225)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-04 16:37:37.607: WARN/System.err(4065):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In Galaxy tablet it's working fine. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is it because your file is a .3gp and your telling the system to play data that is mp3?

Comment: @Blundell  i tried with 3gp bt still the exception is thrown

Answer (score 203):

Url addresses must be preceded by http://

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```

throws an ActivityNotFoundException. If you prepend "http://", problem solved.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Superb! The scheme is a must. `file://` was missing in my case until I changed `Uri.parse()` to `Uri.fromFile()`.

Comment: I was getting a problem when the url was encoded, so note you may need to do `Uri.parse(Uri.decode(encodedString))`

Comment: If this still doesn't work, don't forget to `trim()` the URL string. :-)

Comment: The browser knows where you at. You need to specify the path if you're calling it directly on app.

Comment: what if the url start with file://, and use  Uri.fromFile() still doesn't work

Comment: Ensure that there are no spaces in the URL, as this issue can also occur when there are spaces present in the URL.

Answer (score 63):

If you are also getting this error when trying to open a web page from your android app it is because your url looks like this:

`www.google.com`

instead of:
`https://www.google.com` or `http://www.google.com`

add this code to your Activity/Fragment:

```
 public void openWebPage(String url) {

    Uri webpage = Uri.parse(url);

    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
        webpage = Uri.parse("http://" + url);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

just pass your url to `openWebPage()`. If it is already prefixed with `https://` or `http://` then you are good to go, else the if statement handles that for you

Answer (score 33):

This is the right way to do it.

```
    try
    {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(aFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
    String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
    String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
        String data = e.getMessage();
    }
```

you need to import import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;

Comment: this is the long way to do it :d

Comment: Wrapping that much code in a try block with general exception is usually not a good idea. The behavior here is totally undefined - can you tell which inputs will print a message at a glance? What exceptions will arise, and why? This is a sign of code that has not been tested thoroughly.

Comment: @jbass If you really expect some specific error to happen more or less regularly it is no exception and should be prevented before. The general exeption is a very good idea to catch them all if you don't really care about the reason and just don't want your app to crash. What exactly is undefined here? The last command in the try block starts the activity. Everything before doesn't matter and will be garbage collected. 6 lines in this try block should be a lot? Really? Don't think so.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan As a thought experiment, why not wrap 100% of everything we write in a try block, and why isn't it already done for us by default? Exceptions are more or less designed to crash the program to make bugs more visible, unless they are explicitly caught.

Comment: Ensure that there are no spaces in the URL, as this issue can also occur when there are spaces present in the URL.

Answer (score 28):

**For me when trying to open a link :**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/abc/");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
```

**I got the same error** `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent`

> The problem was because i didnt have any app that can open URLs (i.e.
>   browsers) installed in my phone. So after Installing a browser the
>   problem was solved.

***Lesson : Make sure there is at least one app which handles the intent you are calling ***

Comment: So how can we handle this situation?

Comment: without a custom test device with a custom ROM, you will have an internet activity. This doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: I am having the same issue being reported by a customer. So it seems that there are some devices on which there is no default internet browser installed. How to solve this?

Comment: Catch the error and give an info/dialog/toast that they do not have a working browser?

Comment: See a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479211/intent-resolveactivity-null-but-launching-the-intent-throws-an-activitynotfou. In this case you will know, whether a device contains a default browser (or an application that processes a Deep link).

Comment: It solved my case, where I was trying to open a `.csv` file. There was no app installed to handle `.csv` files, thus the error. To figure it out, I had to temporary change the file extension to something I was sure I had an app to open, `.txt`, and it worked. So I installed an app which could handle spreadsheets.

Comment: Ensure that there are no spaces in the URL, as this issue can also occur when there are spaces present in the URL.

Comment: How can someone live without a browser? I have this error on Pixels, Samsung S23 Ultra, and Galaxy Z Fold. They all have default browsers. Only thing they can do is disable the browser. Why would someone do it?

Answer (score 18):

Answer by Maragues made me check out logcat output. Appears that the path you pass to Uri needs to be prefixed with
    `file:/`

Since it is a local path to your storage.

You may want too look at the path itself too.

```
`05-04 16:37:37.597: WARN/System.err(4065): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/audio-android.3gp typ=audio/mp3 }`
```

Mount point seems to appear twice in the full path.

Comment: this seems to be right answer, but the question is old and OP was last  seen almost 2 months ago

Comment: This is what I did. Sadly, I only read this answer after I found the solutions :)

Comment: Ensure that there are no spaces in the URL, as this issue can also occur when there are spaces present in the URL.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't pass the correct web URL and don't have a browser, ActivityNotFoundException occurs, so check those requirements or handle the exception explicitly. That can resolve your problem.

```
public static void openWebPage(Context context, String url) {
    try {
        if (!URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, " This is not a valid link", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, " You don't have any browser to open web page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ensure that there are no spaces in the URL, as this issue can also occur when there are spaces present in the URL.

Answer (score 10):

Check this useful method:

`URLUtil.guessUrl(urlString)`

It makes google.com -> http://google.com

Answer (score 7):

This exception can raise when you handle `Deep linking` or URL for a browser, if there is no default installed. In case of Deep linking there may be no application installed that can process a link in format `myapp://mylink`.

You can use the [tangerine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479211/intent-resolveactivity-null-but-launching-the-intent-throws-an-activitynotfou) solution for API up to 29:

```
private fun openUrl(url: String) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
    val activityInfo = intent.resolveActivityInfo(packageManager, intent.flags)
    if (activityInfo?.exported == true) {
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "No application that can handle this link found",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
}
```

For API >= 30 see [intent.resolveActivity returns null in API 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535856/intent-resolveactivity-returns-null-in-api-30).

Comment: Yes! an answer that demonstrates how to handle the issue.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid crash below 2 things need to be checked

1. Check if url starts with http or https
2. Check if device has any app that can handle url

**Kotlin**

```
if (url.startsWith("http") || url.startsWith("https")) {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url)).apply{
    // Below condition checks if any app is available to handle intent
    if (resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
           startActivity(this)
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, so I was looking at the intent which is logged in LogCat.  When viewing the video from the Gallery, it called the same Intent.View intent, but set the Type to "audio/*", which fixed my issue, and doesn't require importing MimeTypeMap.  Example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse(path);
intent.setDataAndType(data, "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Also works for videos when using **intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/*")**;

Comment: Ensure that there are no spaces in the URL, as this issue can also occur when there are spaces present in the URL.

Answer (score 4):

If you have these error in your logcat then use these code it help me

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(data.getLocation())), "audio/*");
            try {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
            }
```

also

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MUSIC_PLAYER);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(data.getLocation())), "audio/*");
            try {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("error", e.getMessage());
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Had this exception even changed to

> "audio/*"

But thanx to [@Stan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102014/stan) i have turned very simple but usefully solution:

`Uri.fromFile(File(content))` instead `Uri.parse(path)`

```
 val intent =Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(File(content)),"audio/*")
                    startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 2):

I have two ideas:

First: if you want to play 3gp file you should use mime types "audio/3gpp" or "audio/mpeg"

And second: you can try use method `setData(data)` for `intent` without any mime type.

Comment: still the exception 05-04 17:30:30.022: WARN/System.err(4937): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/mnt/sdcard/audio-android.3gp } is showing

Comment: Is android support your 3gp file? http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 1):

First try this code inside **AndroidManifest**

```
  <application>
       
    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />
 </application>
```

If this code works, so fine. But if not. Try this code from which **class** you want to pass the data or uri.

```
Intent window = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Browser.class);
window.putExtra("LINK", "http://www.yourwebsite.com");
startActivity(window);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using Try and catch. You should use this way

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    intent.setDataAndType(uri, type)    
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "view action"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try checking with any Url like add

https://www.google.com

in path and start activity
if its works than you are adding wrong path

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this case. In my case , it used to happen when I didn't have a browser app in my phone. I installed a browser app and solved my problem. Don't forget to put your code in **Try/Catch** block.