# Gingerbread android crashing on map

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
PostPaid x1 = (PostPaid)accountItems.get(arg2);
String label = ""+x1.getTitle();
String uriBegin = "geo:" + x1.getLatitude() + "," + x1.getLongitude();
String query = x1.getLatitude() + "," +  x1.getLongitude() + "(" + label + ")";
String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.dux_sld_rght_in, R.anim.dux_sld_rght_out);
```

How can I get this done in gingerbread? works on `kitkat` but crashes in `gingertbread`?

log below as requested in the comments.... hope it helps as well./

```
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:24.746614456176758,46.680538177490234?q=24.746614456176758%2C46.680538177490234(al%20%20malaz)&z=16 }
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.netvariant.zain.activity.StoresActivity$1.onItemClick(StoresActivity.java:126)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-12 08:51:46.343: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: worth to note, it crashes on android gingerbread emulator not device. i tested it on kitkat device and it works, but on emulator gingerbread it fails

Comment: Does it work on Kitkat emulator?

Comment: it doesnt work on emulator for api level 15 either.

Comment: I guess, the intent you are providing doe not support for emulators.Can you provide the "uri" ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882656/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-android-intent-action-view

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent.createChooser() method to safely launch the Intent. If no application exists that can handle your intent, a dialog will be displayed telling the user just that.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "dialogTitle"));
```