# got crash when try to use intent to send email (Kotlin)

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I got a crash when I try to send an email using intent with kotlin

here's my function

```
/**
 * intentEmail is called when we need to send email
 *
 * @param price int
 */
fun intentEmail(price: Int) {


    var intent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addressees)
    intent.data= Uri.parse("mailto:")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Just Java order for $name")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, createOrderSummary(price))



    if(intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null){
        startActivity(intent)
    }



}
```

and the crash happens when calling startActivity(intent)

and here's my LogCat
[image]

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this Also, please note that `ACTION_SEND` does not use the `Uri`, so you should remove the `intent.data= Uri.parse("mailto:")` line.

Comment: have you added your permissions in your manifest file ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I attach the LogCat also comment intent.data line but there's no crash but the app doesn't do anything

Comment: @SígvardrÓlavrsson which permissions do you mean?

Comment: You are crashing because there is no activity that matches your Intent.

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you mean? 
I'm newbie in Android and Kotlin

Comment: 1. I would suggest you to read the android docs (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email). It states that for no attachments you should use "ACTION_SENDTO" as action.

Comment: 2. It seems you have no Email-client installed on your phone, which can handle the intent.

Comment: 3. look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22479211/intent-resolveactivity-null-but-launching-the-intent-throws-an-activitynotfou. It describes exactly your problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your phone is not accept this intent action. you should use try catch the avoid this crash. 
you can also use the phone's other "send mail" app, so that  you can find out what's the correct intent.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in

var intent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

when I changed it to

var intent =  Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)

it works fine thanks to @lampenlampen