# Re-direct to an URL on clicking Android Button

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to open a webpage on clicking a button. But, Its not working.
This is my code:

```
ImageButton fbButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fb);
    fbButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent viewIntent = new Intent("Intent.ACTION_VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);
        }
    });
```

Its always going to catch statement.

And Here it is Manifest file permission code:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Error Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.krish.me, PID: 4532
              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=Intent.ACTION_VIEW dat=http://www.facebook.com }
```

Thank you in Advance :)

Comment: use `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` instead of `android.intent.action.view`

Comment: Even after I changed android.intent.action.view to Intent.ACTION_VIEW
its not working

Comment: did you getting any error?

Comment: also replace http to https

Comment: Its always going into that catch statement

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: yes what catch giving error? debug it and post the error. also did you add Internet permission in your Manifest?

Comment: edit your question with new code and post log

Comment: @HemantParmar Error posted :)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38714313/5594218

Comment: install any browser, it seems your device doesn't have any browser installed

Comment: @MinnuKaAnae Bt I already used ` http:// `  in my code

Comment: My device already have browsers

Comment: @Member_9 have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213314/5110595)

Comment: @HemantParmar My basic question not only about facebook. Just about a web page like Google Homepage. I changed that link to `http://www.google.co.in` it still not working

Comment: @Member_9 for Bhavya Gandhi answer your posted comment "No apps can perform this action" that means no app is installed to open the page you are requested

Comment: means ?? 
Bt my device already have browsers. then why its not working

Comment: mention which browsers u have

Comment: Chrome Firefox Opera

Comment: @Member_9 check your code you have used Intent.ACTION_VIEW as string. remove quotations your code will work

Comment: @MinnuKaanae Right.

Comment: Worked :) Finally...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you want to open an URL with Intent* just use `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` in place of `android.intent.action.view`

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com"));
```

**Your code will become like this -**

```
ImageButton fbButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fb);
    fbButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't connect to Internet",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Make sure you has Internet Permission added in the AndroidManifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The problem is i think you dont have any app that can open URLs (i.e. browsers) installed in your phone.

Comment: Member_9 , did you try this

Comment: Hello , did you try adding Internet Permission added in the AndroidManifest file

Comment: follow the above answer

Comment: But, its still returns an error., Please check the error. I added the error part in my question

Comment: The problem is i think you dont have any app that can open URLs (i.e. browsers) installed in your phone.

Comment: Problem is I used "Intent.ACTION_VIEW" instead of Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
```

Use `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` instead `"android.intent.action.view"` .

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose browser"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't connect to Internet",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: When I runs, it displays as Choose Browser at top and at center "No apps can perform this action" message displayed

Comment: In your device install any browser?

Comment: No apps can perform this action"  this message suggest not support any browser for this action.

Comment: You test in device or simulator?

Comment: means ??
I hv chrome, opera and firefox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166019/discussion-between-member-9-and-bhavya-gandhi).